# Importing a React connect component

Tags: reactjs, import, react-redux, export, connect

Ok, so I have a react-redux component exported like this...

```
export default {
component: connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites),
loadData
```

}

Im trying to import this like so...

```
import Sites from '../views/site/sitesView';

const Home = () =>
AccountService.authenticated() ? (
    <Sites/>
) : (....
```

I keep getting the following error...

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Sites}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What would be the correct way to import this?

I have tried...

```
import { Sites } from '../views/site/sitesView';
```

Thanks.

full code...

```
    function loadData(store) {
const state = store.getState();
const companyId = state.accountReducer.userinfo.companyId;

return store.dispatch({
    type: siteActions.SITES_COMPANY_REQUESTED,
    payload: {
        companyId: companyId,
        page: 1,
        items: 50
    }
});
```

}

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
return {
    loading: state.siteReducer.isRequesting,
    companyId: state.accountReducer.userinfo.companyId,
    sites: state.siteReducer.sites,
    countries: state.countryReducer.countries
}
```

}

export default {
    component: connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites),
    loadData
}

Comment: This is a correct way for exporting:

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites)

Comment: @SerhiiPuchkovskyi we export as component like this with loadData function and this is why im getting the error..

Comment: export default {
component: connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites),
loadData

Comment: use this `import Sites from '../views/site/sitesView';` for import. After that, you can use a component like this `<Sites.component />` and a function like this `Sites.loadData()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're exporting by default is an object with multiple properties, not the component alone.

```
import Sites from '../views/site/sitesView';
```

When you do this, the variable `Sites` is assigned the whole object you exported, which includes a property with the component and another with the `loadData` method. This means that, even if you gave it the same name, **this imported `Sites` is not actually the React component**, and that's why React doesn't recognize as such.

The real component is inside of your imported object's `component` property, so in order to render it you'll need to reference it directly:

```
<Site.component />
```

If you'd rather avoid this explicit reference, you should consider changing the way you're exporting the data. **I'll suggest exporting the component only by default, and add individual exports to any other values or functions you usually won't need**, like this:

```
export function loadData () { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites)
```

With this alternative, you could import both things like this:

```
import Sites, { loadData }  from '../views/site/sitesView';
```

`Sites` would now contain only the component, so you could use `<Sites />` directly in your render method. If you need to use any method or other exported values, you can do so with a syntax similar to the above.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

export like this

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites)
```

and Import it as because it is default export

```
import Sites from '../views/site/sitesView';
```

Comment: we export like this and this is why im getting error - export default { component: connect(mapStateToProps)(Sites), loadData}